# How do I connect these two parts of solution?

Tags: differential, differential-amplifier

A differential amplifier is fed in a balanced way with the source resistance Rs which is in series with each base.Show that a mismatch ΔRs between the values of the resistances of the source brings a Vos =(1/2β)*ΔRs

I have drawn the amplifier and solved the exercise up to the point like in the figure.

[image: figure 1]

Now,here I need to find ΔI so then I can find ΔVc=-ΔI*Rc and then Ad=Rc/re and then Vos=ΔVc/Ad

So I know how to solve it.The part I am stuck and where I need your help is finding ΔI.According to the solution manual,the above calculations should result in

[image]

But how do I get this?

Answer (score 1):

Please double check.

I find your equations very confusing as they have Many factors on each side of the equation sign. 
I found :
by applying
\$\Delta V_{b}=\Delta R_{s}\cdot i_{b}\$

\$Ad\cdot\Delta V_{b}=\Delta V_{c}\$

replacing with known values.

\$\frac{Rc}{r_{e}}\cdot\Delta R_{s}\cdot\frac{I}{2\beta}=\Delta I\cdot R_{c}\$

you get

\$
\Delta R_{s}\cdot\frac{1}{r_{e}}\cdot\frac{I}{2\beta}=\underline{\underline{\Delta I}}
\$

As a note I might be a factor 2 off.. But it seems alright.
This is also a low entropy solution, where you see what other factors affects \$\Delta I\$
Hope it helps .